# Why TextView not show all content when rotation to landscape

Tags: android, rotation, textview

`Textview` show half of text when device change its rotation.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/box1"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="#e4eaefec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:freezesText="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text=" text text text text text"/>

                <TableLayout .../>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

in portrait its ok, but in landscape all content of text view not shown. only many words shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent2"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"                     
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=" text text text text text"/>
```

Comment: Ok.this resolve my problem. but the text is dynamic and i have not its line count.how handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to put the layout under scrollview as landscape screen would not able to show the full content of dynamic text.
I believe your text content which is setting dynamic is not able to be consumed in landscape screen.